# Switching direction on the same edge collection within a graph query

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to find my way arround arangodb, being mainly interested in the graph part of it. One thing I try to understand is how I can switch direction on graph traversals on the same edge collection. Using the example graph in https://github.com/arangodb/docs/blob/28b266f143232beb17e5c35cd545d4f3909a1815/3.4/aql/tutorial-traversal.md#childof-relations, how can I get the uncle of Joffrey, e.g. what in Cypher would be (joffrey)-[CHILDOF]->(parent)-[CHILDOF]->(grandparent)<-[CHILDOF]-(uncle)? (I am expecting Tyrion to be found)

Comment: Do you mean the father of Tyrion Lannister by grand-uncle?

Comment: Thanks for asking: i just meant uncle, e.g. Tyrion.

Comment: Wouldn’t your cypher query get all children of the grandparent ?(Jamie, Cersei and Tyron) just trying to understand what you are looking to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AQL, you can not change the direction in which you follow edges of one and the same edge collection in a single traversal, but you can do a follow-up traversal.

For example, you traverse 2..2 OUTBOUND from Joffrey over his parents to his grandparents, then traverse 1..1 INBOUND from the grandparents to the siblings of the parents (Joffrey's uncles and aunts, or given the example dataset, rather only his uncle Tyrion Lannister).

[image: Game of Thrones - ChildOf Graph Visualization]

But beware:

- Following edges from his grandparents (here only Tywin) in INBOUND direction will not only give you Tyrion, but also his parents Jaime and Cersei.
- If it was a single traversal, the default option `uniqueEdges: 'path' would prevent Joffrey's parents from being returned, because they would had been on the path already on the way to Tywin.
- To resolve the problem, we can determine the parents and filter them out in the traversal starting at Tywin in INBOUND direction.
- Another catch is that Joffrey's parents are siblings. To not return Tywin twice in the traversal starting at Joffrey in 2..2 OUTBOUND direction, we can use the traversal option `uniqueVertices: "global", bfs: true` (`bfs` needs to be enabled in order to use `uniqueVertices: "global"`).

So a full query could look like this:

```
LET joffrey = FIRST(
  FOR c IN Characters
    FILTER c.name == "Joffrey"
    LIMIT 1
    RETURN c
)
LET parents = (
  FOR v IN OUTBOUND joffrey ChildOf
    RETURN v
)
LET grandparents = (
  FOR v IN 2..2 OUTBOUND joffrey ChildOf
    OPTIONS {uniqueVertices: "global", bfs: true}
    RETURN v
)
LET unclesAndAunts = (
  FOR gp IN grandparents
    FOR v IN INBOUND gp ChildOf
      OPTIONS {uniqueVertices: "global", bfs: true} // needed?
      FILTER v NOT IN parents
      RETURN v
)
RETURN unclesAndAunts
```

The dataset does not come with a gender attribute, therefore you can't filter like `FILTER v NOT IN parents AND v.gender == "male"` to only get his uncles, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed explaination!